# Why Wired Internet is not working in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: networking, 16.04, ethernet, broadband

You know, I was waiting for this release from last 3 months eagerly. I even downloaded it through torrents to help in anyway I can.

When I installed it and I saw that it doesn't recognized my broadband connection. I installed it on another hard disk (I had two). Then I booted to my Windows 7 again and Internet was working. Then I booted to Ubuntu 16.04 again and there is no Internet. When I saw available connections, it showed Network 1 or I don't know what but something was there; but no IP address.

The main point to note is, when I was seeing these available connections. I tried to delete that single connection it was showing. It got deleted. When I booted into Windows 7, it also stopped recognizing any connection. Troubleshoot was always showing that "there is no cable connected" but it was there! The cable was connected and 100% working on my router! Seems like because I deleted that 'shown connection' in Ubuntu, it did something weird to my hardware. In frustration, I wiped out Windows 7 and reinstalled it; clean. But still not recognition of cable connection.

Next day in evening when I again started my computer, Internet started working again (Thank God). But now it was showing "Network 2" instead of any other name. And it was also connecting and disconnecting automatically. For now because 2 days has passed, it seems stable.

Now I want to know what actually happened? I really wanted to install Ubuntu 16.04 and wanted to use it as my primary OS.

Comment: In Ubuntu, (if it says it is connected) go to Network Menu -> Connection Information -> IPv4 section: what's there?

Comment: @user300458 I have thrown that disk now. It was an old one but I checked it for any bad sectors or other problems, it came healthy but when I installed Ubuntu on it, it started hanging as previously. Now to check only option is to boot it from DVD.

Quote: "In Ubuntu, (if it says it is connected)". No it dosn't say connected. All I see is an empty WiFi icon.

Comment: But does it currently work in Windows 7?

Comment: Yes. It is working fine in Windows 7. I have Gigabyte B85M-D3H-A MoBo, Intel i3 3.50Hz, Corsair 8GB RAM and SeaGate 150GB HD if this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems to be a problem with network interface controller driver in Ubuntu. Just in case, try Linux Mint, some people say that sometimes it works better than Ubuntu.

Comment: If it's a problem then it should be equal for all. Why only me? I have downloaded the same Ubuntu what others downloaded a few days ago on its release. PS: I don't want to run Mint. But thanks for the suggestion. I prefer Ubuntu.

Comment: Im having the same issue...

Comment: Can you describe yours? Like yes you have the same issue but your story? @Aaron

Comment: When I boot up there is no network connection. It doesn't ping. It says I have an IP address, but nothing works. If I reboot again, it might work, then another reboot and it's broken again. It says under Ethernet that I have "Wired connection 1" and "Wired connection 2". So confusing. I didn't add a second. I made my post about  it on the MATE side: https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/no-internet-connection-after-fresh-install-16-04/5385/17

Comment: If I want to provide any log regarding my non-connection, how can I do this? I never used or produced any logs before.

Comment: @user300458 Hi, I have reinstalled Ubuntu wiping Windows 7 completely. I considered your answer. 'Connection information' is grayed out as I am not connected to anything.

Comment: @user300458 No please, I don't want to use Linux Mint. I want to use Ubuntu.

Comment: I want to reopen this question. How can I do this? This question of course isn't going to get any attention now as this is old and drowned.

Comment: I had similar issue with Ethernet. Also my USB 2.0 ports won't work. Next tip helped me to resolve issue: BIOS -> Enable IOMMU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I read somewhere on this forum or I don't know where that a user having similar problem cold booted his computer and internet worked or did I read somewhere that cold booting removes everthing from ROM or RAM (I don't know)? I did the same about 2 days ago and to my surprise, internet worked! Ubuntu 16.04 detected wired connection and it started working. Yay!

Answer (score 2):

so disabling ipv6 was only part of the problem.

this got everything working for me:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf"
sudo sh -c "echo 'net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf"
sudo sh -c "echo 'net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf"
sudo sysctl -p
sudo sed -i 's/false/true/g' /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
sudo reboot -i NOW
```

Comment: How is `firmware-b43-installer` related to wired networking? What does replacing false to true?

Comment: my mistake on b43. not sure why that was included. now, for networkmanager.conf. why don't you open up the file and find out?